# Simple Lottery: Generate new six unique random numbers between 1 and 49

Tags: python, random, integer

- if there are five "short numbers" or all six are "short numbers" (short number is 1 <= number < 25)
- if there are five "large numbers" or all six are "large numbers" (large number is defined as 25 <= number <= 49)
- if at least five out of six numbers are even
- if at least five out of six numbers are odd
- if at least three numbers are successive numbers (e.g., [13, 14, 15, 28, 35, 49] --> draw new six. Or another example is e.g., [5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 38] --> draw new six numbers)

I started programming the first two in my list:

```
import random

def lottery_six():
    setOfSix = set()
    while len(setOfSix) < 6:
        setOfSix.add(random.randint(1,49))
    lottery = list(setOfSix)
    return lottery

def generateLottery(lottery):
    abc = set()
    while (all(i >= 25 for i in lottery) == True) or (all(i < 25 for i in lottery) == True) or \
    (sum(i >= 25 for i in lottery) >= 5) or (sum(i < 25 for i in lottery) >= 5):
        abc = lottery_six()
    return abc

print(generateLottery(lottery_six()))
```

However, that does not work. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: So you win if any of those conditions are true?

Comment: You use a set, are you assuming that the same value cannot be repeated? Such that a list like [1,1,1,1,1,1] is not allowed? The list must be all unique values?

Comment: Yes, the numbers must be unique.

Comment: No, it's just about generating a set that fulfills the above listed requirements.

Comment: 1 of the above, since condition 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this, we will repeat this code until we find a suitable set of values. First we will take the range [1,49] and we will randomly order them and take the first 6 values. Then we check if the range satisfies either of the first 2 requirements. If it does we break the loop and we keep this list of values.

```
while True:
    x = (np.random.permutation(49)+1)[0:6]
    if len([i for i in x if 1<=i<25]) > 4: break
    if len([i for i in x if 25<=i<=49]) > 4: break

print(x)
```

---

The entirety of your code can be written as

```
while True:
    x = (np.random.permutation(49)+1)[0:6]    
    # Check for short
    if len([i for i in x if 1<=i<25]) > 4: break
    # Check for large
    if len([i for i in x if 25<=i<=49]) > 4: break
    # Check for even
    if len([i for i in x if i%2 == 0]) > 5: break 
    # Check for odd
    if len([i for i in x if (i+1)%2 == 0]) > 5: break 
    # Check for successive
    if len([i for ix, i in enumerate(x[0:-2]) 
            if (x[ix+1] - i == 1 and x[ix+2] - x[ix+1] == 1)]) > 0: break

print(x)
```

This will find a list which satisfies your conditions. The last statement is a bit dense, broken down it goes through every value in your list and checks if you have at least 3 successive values `x[ix+1] - i == 1 and x[ix+2] - x[ix+1] == 1`. If this is true, we add the value to the list, if at the end there is at least 1 value in this new list we can conclude that there was at least 3 consecutive values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def lottery_six():
    setOfSix = set()
    while len(setOfSix) < 6:
        setOfSix.add(random.randint(1,49))
    lottery = list(setOfSix)
    return lottery

def generateLottery(lottery):
    abc = set(lottery) #Modified this Line
    while (all(i >= 25 for i in lottery) == True) or (all(i < 25 for i in lottery) == True) or (sum(i >= 25 for i in lottery) >= 5) or (sum(i < 25 for i in lottery) >= 5):
        abc = lottery_six()
    return abc

print(generateLottery(lottery_six()))
```

Comment: What did you do else than I did? I can't figour it out it but yours does work.

Comment: I added comment after line where I modified

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not seem to enter the loop, you may generate a set before while loop. Also these lines seem redundant:

`(all(i >= 25 for i in lottery) == True) or (all(i < 25 for i in lottery) == True)`

Final code :

```
def generateLottery(lottery):
    lottery = lottery_six()
    while sum(i >= 25 for i in lottery) >= 5 or sum(i < 25 for i in lottery) >= 5:
        lottery = lottery_six()
    return lottery

print(generateLottery(lottery_six()))
```